# Why when i call a function with returning value, my onclick event doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, function, events, onclick, return

I minified my work in this simple code that represent my problem:

```
runSomething();

function runSomething(){

    function getRandom(){
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random())*10);
        return random;
    };        

    document.onclick = getRandom();
};
```

There is a external function (`runSomething()`) that contains the next:

- A function called `getRandom` that returns a number between 0 - 9 (that i'm using to a select a random item of a array)
- And a the `document.onclick = getRandom();` that what is supposed to do, is RUN `getRandom();` each time i click any place of the document, to get another new value

But what happens? the `document.onclick = getRandom();` just run once (when the document is being loaded) but nothing happens when a click the document

And `getRandom()` must not be fired when the document is being loaded, because that function is fired in other part of the script, and thats mean that i will get 2 differents new values (remember that `getRandom()` return different numbers each time that is fired)

What i'm doing wrong?

P.S. I still a rookie in JS

P.P.S. Sorry for my english

Comment: After removing `()` from `document.onclick = getRandom();`, think carefully whereto exactly you're returning the newly created random number? It looks like the return value is going to browser's native event handling process. I'm just wondering what it will do with a value?

Comment: I got it, i just didn't know about removing the (). But sadly i just realize after this that i don't need that solution, was another one that i just found, but trust me that it help to me in another part of my script! what unexpected. So i still so grateful for all the help. Anyway, i made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pmff3/), and you can see that i used for a array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `()`

```
document.onclick = getRandom;
```

The `()` will invoke the function immediately on load, you have to pass the function along.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign onClick, you need to assign the function rather than execute it and assign the return value (which is what your `()` do):

```
document.onclick = getRandom;
```